# git shows two master branches and merge commit of them

Tags: git, merge, branch, branching-and-merging, git-extensions

I committed "CRM.Auctions.Data 9.3 schemes support" and then my teammate pulled it and made his own commit "esProxy ip changed"  but when we looked at the repository, we saw this picture:

[image: repo]

These two branches are shown both as master. Why did it go so?

I used GitExtensions and the other git client was VS Code embedded git client. I guess it occurred because VSCode client doesn't support fast-forward merges?

Comment: At a guess—teammate committed before pull, and pull (fetch + merge) created the merge. Pull —rebase usually helps there

Comment: To answer the part "two branches shown both as master" I suggest you review how remote branches work in git. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches (and entire branching chapter in general) What you see is totally normal, you will find master and origin/master in most repos, irrespective of the merge strategy you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is not "two master branches", it is "master" your local master branch and "origin/master", which is the local representation of the master branch on the "origin" remote. This is just because of your confusing title.

And D. Ben Knoble is right, you should have used git pull --rebase to avoid auto-merge when you used pull. From git manual:

> git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD.

You should always use:

```
git fetch origin
```

Before you pull, to see what is going to happen and do a:

```
git pull --rebase
```

In case of divergence.